# Php, MySql select records within current year, month range

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a query to select records that fit current year month range.  Here is my database table:

```
id      name        date_start  date_end
======================================
1       John        2016-05-20  2018-01-01
2       Peter       2017-02-02  2017-05-10
3       Mike        2015-02-02  2017-02-06
```

and my query:

```
SELECT  * FROM users 
WHERE YEAR(date_start) = 2017 
  AND MONTH(date_start) = 01 
  OR YEAR(date_end) = 2017 
  AND MONTH(date_end) = 01
```

So basically I need to select all users where current year/month in this case 2017/01 is within start/end column range.

In above query, only John and Mike records should be selected.

Comment: brackets are your friend `()` `(YEAR(date_start) = 2017 
  AND MONTH(date_start) = 01 )
  OR (YEAR(date_end) = 2017 
  AND MONTH(date_end) = 01 )`

Comment: try `SELECT  * FROM users 
WHERE  (YEAR(date_start) = 2017 
  AND MONTH(date_start) = 01 
  OR YEAR(date_end) = 2017 
  AND MONTH(date_end) = 01)` in your database these three data is above or below of `01/01/2017`.It wont show any data.

Comment: @Chonchol Mahmud that's my point. Im not sure how to query, so the results include dates that are within current year/month

Comment: btw none of your data satisfies your condition. so nothing will be returned

Comment: @Alko your question is not clear.What you want? current year/month data or data with not current month?

Comment: @Chonchol Mahmud I need to select users whose start/end dates fall within current year/month

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just want to find out which users have the date `2017-01-01` within their ranges, defined by the `date_start` and `date_end`.  If so, then the following query should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE date_start <= '2017-01-01' AND date_end >= '2017-01-01'
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it does not select users in 2016

Comment: Are you trying to find users who fall within a certain _range_?  Your original question seems unclear now.

Comment: yes exactly that. Maybe I did not explain correctly. I need to select users whose start/end dates fall within current year/month

Comment: i don't understand what do u mean by does not select users in 2016 since you want within current year/month.

Comment: I updated my answer along with a Fiddle demo which seems to give the results you expect.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thank you. Works perfect. I have accepted your answer.